# Why don't the elements stay in the array?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

In this code I am reading a file that consists of a number of rows. Each  row has 2 words, separated with \t. While I am reading the file, I am creating a dynamically allocated table, that consists of the left column of words in the file. The problem is, the array rows appears to be correct only in the loops. When I try to print rows[i] outside the loops, the elements disappear. Sorry if I didn't explain very well, I am new to the C language..!

```
char line[21];
int i=0;
FILE *infile=fopen("words.txt", "r");
if(infile == NULL){
    printf("The Input File is Null! Please Re-Run the program.");   
        return 1;             
}
int numofrows=11;
char **rows=malloc(sizeof(char*)*numofrows);
//read the file
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL) {
    english = strtok(line, search); //this is the word of the left column
    englength=strlen(english);//the length of the word
    for(i=0;i<numofrows;i++){
        rows[i] = malloc(11*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(rows[i], english);
    }
}
        //this doesnt work     
    for(i=0;i<numofrows;i++){    
            printf(rows[i]);
        }
```

The last for loop should print each word in the array rows, instead, nothing is being printed.

Comment: Use `numofrows` instead of `11` when calling `malloc` to avoid slip-ups.

Comment: @tadman I think you mean `englength` instead of 11. @Georgia. Turn on all compiler warnings and you would have noticed this! `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @bitmask In that case, `englength + 1` to accommodate the trailing NUL, if not a `strdup` call to avoid all that mess.

Comment: @tadman That's correct.

Comment: `rows[i] = malloc(11*sizeof(char));` -> `rows[i] = malloc(englength + 1);` **Validate** EVERY allocation before using the block of memory, e.g. `if (rows[i] == NULL) { perror("malloc-rows[i]"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: You have two nested loops, but I think there should be only one loop over the rows. The index `i` corresponds to the line number. Now, you are copying the same word `numrows` times for each line you've read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to write each new line into a new slot in the array. Later, when printing the array make sure not to read more lines than previously stored.

This is a starting point for you, but there are several things more that could be improved.

```
  unsigned i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i<numofrows && fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL; ++i) {
    char* english = strtok(line, search); //this is the word of the left column
    unsigned englength=strlen(english);//the length of the word
    rows[i] = malloc((englength+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(rows[i], english);
  }
  for(unsigned j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("%s\n",rows[j]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement `printf(rows[i]);` is badly formed. Try `printf("%s", rows[i]);`

Comment: There's also [`puts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) if formatting doesn't matter.

Comment: Or `fputs` if you want newline control.